# Serial communication with JAVA

Tags: serial, communication

I installed pi4j.deb and I I wanted to compile a code using this library but I got this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/pi4j/wiringpi/Serial
at mainclass.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pi4j.wiringpi.Serial
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

and you can see the code.
I downloaded the library from "http://get.pi4j.com/download/pi4j-1.1.zip".
would you help me finding it's problem.

```
//@author Arsalan


package mainclass;

import com.pi4j.wiringpi.Serial;

public class MainClass {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int serialPort = Serial.serialOpen(Serial.DEFAULT_COM_PORT,9600);
        if(serialPort==-1) {
            System.out.println("Serial Failed!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("serial OK!");
        }
        Serial.serialPuts(serialPort, "Hey! I'm PI's Serial!!!");
        Serial.serialDataAvail(serialPort);
    }

}
```

Comment: What has **your research** found so far?

Comment: Looks like you need to put the location of the compiled pi4j stuff in `$JAVALIBPATH`.

Answer (score 1):

This is ultimately a question about Java that has nothing really to do with Raspberry Pi or pi4j.  You need to provide the path to external libraries / sources when you compile and when you run.  How you provide the path in Java depends on what type of resource you want to access.  I don't know pi4j, but I'd guess that you need BOTH the `path` and the `classpath` to include appropriate values.  The `path` to point to the native libraries that I assume underlie the implementation and the `classpath` to point to the `jar` file with the Java classes.

The `path` is typically set at the operating system level (or the shell level if you're in a linux-type system).  The `classpath` can be set as an environment variable or passed as an option on the command line to the various Java commands (e.g. `java` and `javac`).  You'll need to read the documentation to get a full handled on this.

See, for example, the [PATH and CLASSPATH tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) for Oracle.